# Heroku restore snapshot XML Error

Tags: xml, heroku, restore, snapshot

I am getting an XML error when I try and access the Heroku Postgres backup snapshot. I cant download it from the website and it will not restore!

Is anyone else seeing this error downloading or restore a snapshot?

This is the error from the Heroku website:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>app*****@heroku.com/a193.dump</Key>
<RequestId>****************</RequestId>
<HostId>
*************/*************************
</HostId>
</Error>`
```

Regards
Kevin

Comment: Can you explain more about you environment and what application do you use (supposed it's JDBC)? May be you need to try to follow an error 'The specified key does not exist' and solve it, upload keys?

Comment: Raise a ticket for this please.